# Where is the Collad exporter window in Blender?

Tags: export, collada

I was reading the manual for Blender and I saw that there is a section just for [Collada Exporting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/collada.html#collada-exporter). I am trying to find this dropdown spinner/window in Blender. I looked under the addons tab under preferences and it was not there. Where can I find the COLLADA Export window, as shown in the blender manual? (Blender 2.90)

Comment: File > Export > Collada. But the image in the manual is a bit out of date.

Comment: So, what you are telling me, is that there isn't a way to specify settings when exporting as a COLLADA file? I saw some settings there that I find relevant to my application. All there exists is a way to export the file, and that is it?